# Can someone help me define these 3 lines of code?

Tags: libgdx

Can somebody help me with what these lines of code are actually saying?

```
 if (!(x == snakeX && y == snakeY)) batch.draw(texture, x, y);
```

and

```
 for (BodyPart bodyPart : bodyParts) {
        bodyPart.draw(batch);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is what you could say about those lines

```
 if (!(x == snakeX && y == snakeY)) batch.draw(texture, x, y);
```

> if some coordinate* (x,y) are not equal to the snake coordinate
>   (position of the snake in the screen) then a texture will be drawn in
>   the screen at the (x,y) position of the screen

```
 for (BodyPart bodyPart : bodyParts) {
        bodyPart.draw(batch);
    }
```

> drawing all the part of the body of snake which each par is class
>   named `BodyPart`

this code refer to the classic game of snake

good luck

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought but for the if statement isn't it the same as 
     If (x!=snakeX &&y!=snakeY)
Because when I did the above it wasn't working right.

Comment: !(x == snakeX && y == snakeY) don't equal (x!=snakeX &&y!=snakeY)  but it equal that (x != snakeX || y != snakeY)

Comment: don't forget to accept the answer if it was helpful, good luck

Comment: I won't but I just want to make sure I understand so its an or? Isnt || saying this OR that?

Comment: exactly : !(x == snakeX && y == snakeY) equivalent to: !(x == snakeX) !(&&) !(y == snakeY) which is equivalent to : x != snakeX || y != snakeY